# API Gateway Express Lambda setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I have an express server hosted on a Lambda with routes like GET "/profiles". I have tied this lambda to API Gateway REST endpoints/resources at "/profile/general". I would also like to be able to access req.apiGateway.event.queryStringParameters.token in my Lambda express middleware. "token" is listed as a query string under the Method Request for /profile/general ANY. The methods for /profile/general are listed as ANY, because the express server has many routes, like the GET to /profiles and a POST to another route.

[image: api-gateway-screenshot]

With this setup, if I want to send a GET request to "/profiles" in the express lambda, will the overall URL be ".../profile/general/profiles?token=123456" ? Or is there perhaps a better/easier way to set this up, perhaps with a /{proxy+} resource somewhere?